# VNC viewer infinite connection

Tags: android-11, vnc, termux, vnc-viewer, samsung

I have a Samsung Galaxy A10s with Android 11 One UI 3. Recently there was a problem: VNC viewers do not work. I enter, for example, localhost:1 (I want to connect to the Termux VNC server), I connect, and the connection window hangs indefinitely, and then a timeout appears. And so with any VNC viewers (I tried AVNC, bVNC, VNC Viewer). I tried AVNC, bVNC, VNC Viewer, change `localhost:1` to `localhost:5901`, but nothing works. Help me please!

> Translated by Google Translate from Russian

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question so is off-topic here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by allowing background activity in the Termux settings.